# Photoshop: Different workspaces in photoshop like Firefox workspaces

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to organize your open files in different workspaces? I want to have the same setup, but different files like Firefox workspaces.

For example, choose "sign in" workspace and have 3 tabs for sign in pages, choose "create account" workspace and have 5 tabs for create account pages etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, its possible.

Comment: @joojaa How can you do it? Where to look? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set things up as you'd like them and then choose `Window > Workspace > New Workspace...`

Note that the workspace controls the Photoshop UI, not open documents.